# Does android_tutorial_pubsub connect to other ROS Masters?

Tags: ros, tutorial, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've built and installed android_tutorial_pubsub from source, but it doesn't seem to connect to a specified ros master on a host computer. I'm running it on an Asus Transformer Prime with Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0.3). Should I expect this to work in this way?

```
rosjava_core:
parent: 954:ff50a6891058 tip
 merge
branch: default

android_core:
parent: 152:b144c7149c66 tip
 Initial import of android_core documentation.
branch: default
```

I've also tried it on a Honeycomb tablet (Iconia Tab) and a Gingerbread Nexus One (2.3.6) all with the same behavior, so I'm assuming I'm missing something.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30726/does-android_tutorial_pubsub-connect-to-other-ros-masters?/) by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5809 on 2012-03-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-03-28**:
Additionally, android_tutorial_camera exits when I try to open it with the error "Unfortunately , CameraTutorial has stopped."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the answer here: http://answers.ros.org/question/12771/running-android_tutorial_pubsub

The tutorial starts its own roscore. You'll have to modify it to connect to a different one.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1